# Strong and a weak grid?

Tags: three-phase, power-engineering, simulink

> What is difference between a strong and a weak grid? How can these be simulated in simulink?

?

Answer (score 1):

It's a fairly complex question but the short circuit current is a good indication of how strong your grid is. More inductance between you and the "core" of the grid = weaker grid.